Error: type ConsensusHook is not a member of trait cumulus_pallet_parachain_system::Config
When trying to upgrade Parachain for Asynchronous Backing compatibility following this guide: https://wiki.polkadot.network/docs/maintain-guides-async-backing
I get the following error when compiling:
  error[E0437]: type `ConsensusHook` is not a member of trait `cumulus_pallet_parachain_system::Config`
     --> /runtime/src/lib.rs:437:5
      |
  437 |     type ConsensusHook = ConsensusHook;
      |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ not a member of trait `cumulus_pallet_parachain_system::Config`


The issue was that parachian had Polkadot SDK dependecies on version 1.9.0, and at that time ConsensusHook was optional feature which needs to be included Cargo.toml:
cumulus-pallet-parachain-system = { git = "https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-sdk",  branch = "release-polkadot-v1.9.0", features = ["parameterized-consensus-hook"] }

In later version parameterized-consensus-hook feature has been removed: https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-sdk/pull/4380
